# Вызов переопределенной функции из переменной базового класса

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void say()
    {
        cout << "I'm a parent!" << endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    virtual void say()
    {
        cout << "I'm a child!" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Child c;
    Parent p = c;
    p.say();
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Данный код выдает в консоль:

```
I'm a parent!
Hello World!
```

Можно ли вызвать переопределенную функцию из переменной базового класса? (тоесть, чтобы выводилось `I'm a child!`) Если нельзя, то можно ли как-нибудь вызвать ее каким-либо способом, кроме использования указателей?

Comment: Вопрос: зачем? Для чего?

Comment: @LShadow77 для хранения в переменной и дальнейшей сериализации из обьекта.

Comment: для этого есть указатели и ссылки. По-другому никак. Т.е., в вашем случае так: Parent* p = &c; p->say(). Ну или через ссылку как в ответе.

Comment: Если объект имеет тип базового класса, то и методы у него будут именно базового класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Но только для этого надо использовать ссылку:

```
Parent& p = c;
```

Так, как написали вы - вы получаете объект `Parent` (со срезкой), и вызывается, соответственно, его метод - здесь нет никакого `Child`.

Comment: только ссылка - это вид указателя, а автор вопроса почему-то не хочет указатели.

Comment: @LShadow77,  Откуда у вас эта информация?  Какие виды имеют указатели вообще?..

Comment: @LShadow77 - ссылки не указатели

Comment: @KoVadim  ссылка - это фактически указатель, для которого явно не требуется операция разименования (*). Разве нет?

Comment: @KoVadim Во всяком случае не является ошибкой думать о ссылках именно так. Ну а в случае передачи ссылки в качестве параметра функции, она передаётся именно как указатель (адрес) на переменную, на которую она ссылается.

Comment: Очень распространенное заблуждение. Да, компилятор может реализовать ссылке через указатели, но не обязан. Более того, он может делать оптимизации на базе этого - например, ссылка не бывает nullptr(обычно)

Comment: @KoVadim это не заблуждение, а представление, при том вполне работоспособное. Вполне естественно, что компилятор может делать оптимизации, он их и делает. Например, в выше приведённом ответе под ссылку p не будет отведено отдельное место в памяти, так как это в данном случае не имеет смысла. Однако, если ссылка является параметром функции, то с точки зрения машинного кода - это чистейшей воды указатель! Понятно, что он не может оказаться NULL, или быть изменён в теле функции - компилятор просто не предоставляет средств для этого (ведь он по определению уже разименован).